# Weierstrass theorem and compactness

Tags: functions, compactness

On my book the statement of Weierstrass theorem is: If $f$ is a continuous function $f:A\subseteq X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a compact set $C$, where $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $X$ is a metric space, then argmax$f$ and argmin$f$ are non-empty and **compact** sets.

I have a couple of proof to demonstrate that argmin and argmax are nonempty but I cannot understand why they are also compact sets.

Have you any hint/proof to see that?

Comment: A point is a closed set. Also you have that $f$ is continous and $C$ compact. By the way what is $A$?

Comment: I added the info you need. I've forgotten to describe the sets

Comment: When $A$ is the domain of $f$ and $f$ is defined on the compact set $C$, what's the difference between $A$ and $C$?

Comment: Since it is in the chapter about optimization, I think that $C$ has to be interpreted as the constraint in a constrained optimization problem, whereas $A$ is the domain of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Argmin$(f)$ and Argmax$(f)$ are closed (continuous preimages of point sets, which are closed).
- Argmin$(f)$ and Argmax$(f)$ are subsets of $C$.
- $C$ is compact
- Closed subsets of compact sets are compact. ([x](http://planetmath.org/closedsubsetsofacompactsetarecompact))

Thus, Argmin$(f)$ and Argmax$(f)$ are compact.